# 'Segoe UI' Font is not working in converted PDF from HTML

Tags: html, pdf, sejda

I have used 'Segoe UI' font in HTML..HTML is converted to PDF using Sejda API, Then it is displaying default font on behalf of Segoe UI font..

```
    .ref {
        text-align: left;
        color: #717171;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the font issue when converting HTML to PDF using Sejda API you can do the following things:

1. Add a fallback font:

   ```css
   font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
   ```
2. Embed 'Segoe UI' font using @font-face in CSS. This method allows you to include the font directly in your HTML, making it available even if it's not installed on the system performing the conversion:

   ```css
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Segoe UI';
       src: url('path/to/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('path/to/font.woff') format('woff');
       font-weight: 700;
   }
   ```
3. It's also important to review the Sejda API documentation to ensure that there are no specific requirements for it. Check Sejda API documentation for font-related requirements: https://developers.sejda.com/

Answer (score 1):

try `font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;` or `font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;`